# Mapbox: Filtering out markers in a Leaflet Omnivore KML layer

Tags: leaflet, kml, mapbox

I am exporting Google Directions routes as KML and displaying them on a Mapbox map by reading them with Omnivore and adding them to the map,

The Google KML stores each route as two **Places** (the start and end points) and one **LineString** (the route). In Mapbox I would like to show only the routes, that is to *filter out the markers* somehow. I'm displaying markers out of my own database and the Google markers clutter it up.

Here is my code. I change the styling of the LineStrings just to show that I can, but do not know what magic call(s) to make to not display the Points. 
Thanks.

```
runLayer = omnivore.kml('data/xxxx.kml')
  .on('ready', function() {
    var llBnds = runLayer.getBounds();
    map.fitBounds(llBnds);

    this.eachLayer(function (layer) {

      if (layer.feature.geometry.type == 'LineString') {
        layer.setStyle({
          color: '#4E3508', 
          weight: 4
        });
      }

      if (layer.feature.geometry.type == 'Point') {
        //
        // Do something useful here to not display these items!!
        //
      }                 
    });
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Many possible solutions:

- Most straight forward from the code you provided, just use the [`removeLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-removelayer) method on your `runLayer` Layer Group when you get a `'Point'` feature.
- Cleaner solution would be to filter out those features before they are even converted into Leaflet layers, through a [custom GeoJSON Layer Group](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore#custom-layers) passed as 3rd argument of `omnivore.kml`, with a specified [`filter`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-filter) option:

```js
var customLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  filter: function(geoJsonFeature) {
    // my custom filter function: do not display Point type features.
    return geoJsonFeature.geometry.type !== 'Point';
  }
}).addTo(map);

var runLayer = omnivore.kml('data/xxxx.kml', null, customLayer);
```

You can also use the [`style`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-style) and/or [`onEachFeature`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-oneachfeature) options on `customLayer` to directly apply your desired style on your LineString.

Comment: Thank you sir (or madam :) 

Solution one worked(!)

But as you say Solution two is cooler, and it worked also ... after I changed "L.geoJSON" to "L.geoJson".  Also the ".addTo(map)" is unnecessary since we're passing it to Omnivore. 

I had tried and failed to filter them one they were added to the map, but it's way better to filter on the import and not add them at all.

thanks again!

Comment: `L.geoJson` is for Leaflet 0.x. You should consider upgrading to Leaflet 1.x.

Comment: thanks - version v0.2.0 is used in all the Mapbox examples I've seen, so I didn't know any better...