# Mysterious "markers" using Leaflet (with Omnivore and the MapQuest plugins)

Tags: leaflet, mapquest

I'm using Leaflet (with omnivore and the MapQuest tile plugins) to display a map with colored polygons.  The map and polygons look/work fine, but there are these mysterious blue markers everywhere.

[image: Map with stray markers]

There's nothing in the JS about markers at all, and if I comment out the `polygon.addTo(map);` line, the markers disappear.  So they're definitely related to the polygons, even though they're not directly positioned on the polygons.

Any idea why the markers are appearing, or how I can make them disappear?

**SOLVED: It turns out that the problem was that I'm using MSSQL's ".Reduce(n)" function to simplify the polygons (for performance), and if you simplify the polygons too far, the results have "Point(...)" items in them - which leaflet renders as markers!**

Now, off to figure out why MSSQL is turning things into points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Most probably your `polygon` variable is a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group built by the omnivore plugin, and the data you feed it with contains `"Point"` type geometries.

If you do not specify anything special to handle these points, Leaflet will render them with this default blue marker icon.

In that case, you could simply filter out those point features, whether after omnivore processing (use the ready event) or using a custom GeoJSON Layer Group with its `filter` option. There should be other posts describing such solutions.

See e.g. [Mapbox: Filtering out markers in a Leaflet Omnivore KML layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222193/mapbox-filtering-out-markers-in-a-leaflet-omnivore-kml-layer/44229623#44229623)

If you are not in this case, you would have to provide more information for people to be able to help you. Typically code that you use to build your `polygon` layer and sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I don't think the polygon data contains any points - I've used the same data in other apps without problems, and the following query finds no rows:

`select *
from MapData.dbo.GeoUS_MSAMaps 
where MapData.ToString() like '%point%'`

Comment: I've updated the question with the complete JS code for the app.  This whole thing is just CRAZY: I spent maybe an hour or two putting everything together, and I've probably spent 6-8 hours now trying to figure out where the markers are coming from! ANY ideas are welcome!

Comment: Without some sample data that reproduces the issue, I do not think I will be able to provide any further help...

Comment: Yup, you were right about the POINT() data structures - the original data didn't have any, but the polygons were being simplified "on the fly" (in the web service), and that was resulting in points.  THANK YOU for your invaluable help!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your issue. This also tells others that the question is solved. You also have the possibility to add your own _answer_ to your question.